# What additional nutrition should I consider when starting to train in Muay Thai?

Tags: nutrition, muscle-recovery, martial-arts

I'm working out 3 days a week for 1 hour - Muay Thai kickboxing + the same amount of time pumping iron at the gym. The Muay Thai involves:

[image]

- Full contact sparring
- Leg and arm conditioning (taking hits)
- Intensive core, leg and arm cardio

I have a reasonable healthy western diet, but it's quite random and unhealthy at times too.

Are there either any specific nutritional based additions or changes that I should make to my diet to ensure I get enough to maintain current muscle and recover from my activities?

I don't include my current diet because I only want core or optional food products that would enhance regular hard sparring (muscle damage/bruising). It's a bonus if such things are already part of my diet.

Comment: Are you going at this alone or with a trainer/camp? If going with a trainer/camp then they should have a regimine that they use or they can build one for you.

Answer (score 4):

I have three things that I changed about my diet when I started training in martial arts:

- Drink more water. I drink a gallon a
  day. You'd be surprised how much you
  sweat while working out. Have you
  ever weighed yourself before and
  after a heavy leg day for example?
- Take a fish oil or other omega-3
  fatty acid supplement. Once you get
  into training kicking and punching in
  earnest, your knees and elbows may
  start to ache. I found that a daily
  fish oil dose cured almost all my
  aches and pains.
- Finally, take a multi and lift heavy.
  You said you have a randomly healthy
  diet already. I'm not sure what that
  means, but adding a multi vitamin
  couldn't hurt. This is pretty
  standard advice for anybody however.

Comment: During wrestling practice I would lose 5-8 pounds each practice.